# How to implement 360 degree image rotation

Tags: javascript, web, 3d, webgl, client-side

I want to implement something to rotate 3D image by 360 degrees on client side,

somethig like [this](http://www.uize.com/examples/3d-rotation-viewer.html)

1) is WebGL best to do this ?

2) from where I can start ?

Comment: css transforms would be the most simple

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, use a css transform to define a class called `spin`

```
img.spin { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

Then add the class to your image

```
<img src="your image" class="spin" />
```

[...or if you're feeling animated](http://jsfiddle.net/za13jcby/1/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes twist {
  0%   { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(359deg); }
}

img.twist {
    -webkit-animation: twist 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    twist 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      twist 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         twist 5s infinite; 
}
```

Comment: This literally the best possible answer to such a question.

Comment: what axis would you like to rotate around? you can do a 3dtransform just as easily http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Comment: And, if you must use webGL, take a look at [three.js](http://threejs.org/). But for what you are describing, css transforms are the obvious choice

Comment: But, thats all I care about Winchestro!